# Why is this attribute redundant ? What is the closure for these attribute sets?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a functional dependency set F = {ABH->CK, A->D, C->E,
BGH->L, L->AD, E->L, BH->E}.

Why is A redundant in ABH->CK?

What is the closure for AB, BH and AH?

Comment: You don't have a "functional relation". You have a set, F, of *functional dependencies* that hold in some relation. Also, what do you mean by "redundant"? And do you mean the closure of *set of FDs* {AB, BH, AH} or maybe the closures of each of the *determinants* AB, BH & AH? You are not writing clearly. Also please show what you have so far and what reference you are following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BH -> E -> L -> AD`, we can say that `BH -> A` by applying Armstrong's rule of transitivity twice, followed by decomposition. From there, if we include the trivial FD `BH -> BH`, we then see that `BH -> ABH`. Again using transitivity, `BH -> ABH -> CK` can be reduced to `BH -> CK`, i.e. `A` is not required to determine `CK`.

The closure of a set of FDs with respect to a given determinant can be computed by again using Armstrong's rules to combine all functional dependencies following directly or indirectly from the selected determinant. For example, for `BH`:

```
BH -> BH (trivial)
BH -> BEH (union with BH -> E)
BH -> BEHL (union with BH -> L which follows from BH -> E -> L)
BH -> ABDEHL (union with BH -> AD which follows from BH -> L -> AD)
BH -> ABCDEHKL (union with BH -> CK since BH -> ABH -> CK)
```

so `BH* = ABCDEHKL`. Note that `G` is not derived so `BH` is not a candidate key.